# Using different time periods in one Azure log query

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

So I have an Azure log query (KQL) that takes in a date parameter, like check log entries for the last X amount of days. In this query I look up values from two different logs, and I would like to have the two lookups use different dates for the respective logs. To get an idea of what I'm looking for, see the query below which is almost what I have now, with a bit of pseudo code where I can't quite figure out how to structure it.

```
let usernames = LogNumberOne
| where TimeGenerated > {timeperiod:start} and TimeGenerated < {timeperiod:end}
| bla bla bla lots of stuff
let computernames = LogNumberTwo
| where TimeGenerated > {timeperiod:start} - 2d
| where bla bla bla lots of stuff
usernames
| join kind=innerunique (computernames) on session_id
| some logic to display table
```

So from LogNumberOne I want the values within the specified time period, but from LogNumberTwo I want the values from the specified time period plus another 2 days before that. Is this possible or do I need another parameter? I have tried with the query above, so `{timeperiod:start} - 2d`, but that doesn't seem to work, it just uses the timeperiod:start value without subtracting 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

See next variant for using join with filter later.

```
let usernames  = datatable(col1:string, session_id:string, Timestamp:datetime )
[
'user1', '1', datetime(2020-05-14 16:00:00),
'user2', '2', datetime(2020-05-14 16:05:30),
];
let computernames  =
datatable(session_id:string, ComputerName:string, Timestamp:datetime )
[
'1', 'Computer1', datetime(2020-05-14 16:00:30),
'2', 'Computer2', datetime(2020-05-14 16:06:20),
];
usernames
| join kind=inner (
    computernames
    | project-rename ComputerTime = Timestamp
) on session_id
| where Timestamp between(ComputerTime .. (-2d))
```

In case large sets of join are involved - use technique described in the following article: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/join-timewindow

```
let window = 2d;
let usernames  = datatable(col1:string, session_id:string, Timestamp:datetime )
[
'user1', '1', datetime(2020-05-13 16:00:00),
'user2', '2', datetime(2020-05-12 16:05:30),
];
let computernames  =
datatable(session_id:string, ComputerName:string, Timestamp:datetime )
[
'1', 'Computer1', datetime(2020-05-14 16:00:30),
'2', 'Computer2', datetime(2020-05-14 16:06:20),
];
usernames
| extend _timeKey = range(bin(Timestamp, 1d), bin(Timestamp, 1d)+window, 1d)
| mv-expand _timeKey to typeof(datetime)
| join kind=inner (
    computernames
    | project-rename ComputerTime = Timestamp
    | extend _timeKey = bin(ComputerTime, 1d)
) on session_id, _timeKey
| where Timestamp between(ComputerTime .. (-window))
```

Comment: I think either I don't understand your answer or maybe you misunderstood my question. LogNumberOne and LogNumberTwo are not logs that I create myself, rather logs that already exist in Azure that are ingested from for instance Office365. Also LogNumberTwo contains a massive amount of entries, tens of thousands per day so I would like to filter it before the join to avoid unnecessary large operations.

Comment: Added additional info and recommendations